# Is asking "How to do X?", but tag some external libraries, a hint of recommend external libraries?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

For example [the original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75759266/1) of  [Merging PDF files from list of files with full path : input1.pdf ; input2.pdf ; output.pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759266/merging-pdf-files-from-list-of-files-with-full-path-input1-pdf-input2-pdf) doesn't ask for recommended tools for merging 2 PDF directly, but tags some external libraries like "pdfbox", "jspdf" ,"pdfrw" at once. Is that requesting libraries?

Should we close a question with "recommend tools" that doesn't request external tools directly in the question title and body, but contain tags with multiple external libraries?

Another question that has multiple library tags: [How to identify uneven spacing in a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75742473/how-to-identify-uneven-spacing-in-a-pdf)

Comment: Even if we keep aside the matter of recommendation questions that question is closable for lacking focus because it asks for multiple things: 1) A solution using powershell without any external tool 2) If the previous is not possible then a solution using some package / 3rd party tool, it doesn't even specify a specific one and lists three different ones in the tags which  are further for three different programming languages.

Comment: Wow. The libraries tagged can't even all be used in the same programming language!

Comment: @philipxy I don't see anything in any version of the question about *not* using libraries. OPs omit that kind of thing from the question text all the time, expecting the tags and especially the *title* to carry the load. Especially in the Python tag I've seen all kinds of questions with a code dump that's clearly using Pandas and/or NumPy with no mention of this in the prose (and often those tags are also missing - on the other hand, sometimes people do tag Pandas and NumPy, but not Python).

Comment: _"Do you think it is possible to do that with Command Prompt or Windows Powershell without any specific tool to install"_ OP is very specifically asking for a solution without libraries, in both revisions of the question...

Comment: @Cerbrus But they went on to say "Or it is not possible to do that without a specific library ? (like pdfrw python library) How would you do ?"

Comment: @philipxy technically, that's not him asking to use a library...

Comment: SO let's not assume the worst? :D

Comment: @Cerbrus My edit took them to be asking about how to do it without libraries & that tagging just because they mentioned libraries as examples of what they would do without was wrong.

Comment: A hint is not proof. A hint is a trigger to investigate, not to pass judgement. It might just as well be people who are filling out all five tag slots because that'll surely get them answers faster. You essentially already answered your own question based on your choice of terminology.

Answer (score 1):

If *one* such library is tagged, then the question is definitely not seeking recommendations. The natural inference is that the question is about *"how to use that library"* to solve the problem.
Consider whether this is adequate information to make the question answerable.
(In particular, is there a **clear** specification for what the program needs to do?)

Consider editing the question to make it explicit that the solution should use that library; and proceed normally.

If *multiple* such libraries are tagged, assuming that they are libraries that fundamentally fill the same niche, then the question almost certainly *"Needs More Focus"*. Please vote or flag to close. It's just as if the question were tagged with multiple programming languages. That's *only* appropriate when the question is about interfacing bits of code written in all of those languages to each other.

(In particular, *"how do I do X thing that's easy in language Y, in language Z?"* is *not a language-Y question*, and should ideally be rewritten to explain "X thing" without reference to language Y.)

Tags aside, the *"recommend libraries"* close reason is *not* for questions where OP has already **researched and identified** some libraries and is asking people to *choose between them*. Those questions should instead be closed as *"Opinion-based"*.

Comment: _"the "recommend libraries" close reason is not for questions where OP has already researched and identified some libraries and is asking people to choose between them."_ citation needed. IMHO the recommend offsite resources close reason is a more specific version of opinion-based, and also applies if you've preselected a number of libraries, and you're asking people which one they'd _recommend_.

Comment: If it worked like that, then there would be no reason to have a separate close reason, since it would clearly be a strict subset of "opinion-based".